# Optimize Javascript function with many (maybe?) loops inside

Tags: javascript

I have the following function using in my application:

```
applyFormSectionIdsToControls: function(formSections) {
    if (!formSections.length) return;

    var formSectionIds = [];

    for (var i = 0, ii = formSections.length; i < ii; i++) {
        formSectionIds.push(parseInt(formSections[i].id));
    };

    for (var i = 0, ii = formSections.length; i < ii; i++) {
        var affectedWidgets = $.grep(application_widgets, function(item) {
            return (($.inArray(item.widget_key, ['nextbutton', 'dropdown', 'radiobuttons']) >= 0) && (item.parent_id == formSections[i].id));
        });

        for (var j = 0, jj = affectedWidgets.length; j < jj; j++) {
            if (affectedWidgets[j].widget_key == 'nextbutton' && (typeof affectedWidgets[j].settings.default_next_step != 'undefined' && affectedWidgets[j].settings.default_next_step > 0)) {
                var _next_step = parseInt(affectedWidgets[j].settings.default_next_step);

                if ($.inArray(_next_step, formSectionIds) == -1) {
                    affectedWidgets[j].settings.default_next_step = formSectionIds[_next_step - 1];
                }
            }
            if (affectedWidgets[j].widget_key == 'radiobuttons' || affectedWidgets[j].widget_key == 'dropdown') {
                for (var k = 0, kk = affectedWidgets[j].settings.answers; k < kk; k++) {
                    var _next_step = parseInt(affectedWidgets[k].settings.answers[k].next_step);

                    if ($.inArray(_next_step, formSectionIds) == -1) {
                        affectedWidgets[k].settings.answers[k].next_step = formSectionIds[_next_step - 1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I'm looking for any hints how to refactor it, as I think there are too many `for` loops.

Comment: That's just \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$. not quite sure what you mean by "too many `for`-loops ... sure there is some optimizations that I see, but ...

Comment: The title "Optimize Javascript function with many (maybe?) loops inside" applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. At the same time, you need to tell us what this code does, ideally with a sample of the corresponding HTML. (Press Ctrl-M to make a live demo.) See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Look, ma, no loops!

But seriously, if you were concerned about performance I don't think it's a problem of nested loops *per se*, `$.grep` in the loop concerns me much more. Especially since you're doing basically the same `grep` over and over!

After grep, neither `item.parent_id` nor `i` are used again. Looks like we can just cycle through all widgets in one `$.grep`, and that's exactly what we're going to do.

Also, what you're doing with `item.widget_key` begs for a `switch` statement - or, at least, having those `radiobutton` and `dropdown` typed twice bugs me and begs for a well-placed typo to cause lots of frustration.

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you do with `default_next_step`, so `correctNextStep` probably needs some refinement (like, what if `next_step - 1` is not a valid forum section index either?) but the code is supposed to work exactly the same as yours. (or not work, hard to say without test cases:D)

```
const inArray = (needle, haystack) => (-1 != haystack.indexOf(needle));
const parseIntIfDefined = (item) => ('undefined' === typeof(item) ? null : parseInt(item));

const applyFormSectionIdsToControls = function(formSections) {
  if (!formSections.length) return;

  const formSectionIds = formSections.map((section) => parseInt(section.id));
  const correctNextStep = (nextStep) => {
    if (inArray(nextStep, formSectionIds)) return nextStep;
    return formSectionIds[nextStep - 1];
  };

  $.grep(application_widgets, (item) => {
    if (!inArray(parseInt(item.parent_id), formSectionIds)) return;

    switch (item.widget_key) {
      case 'nextbutton':
        const defaultNextStep = parseIntIfDefined(item.settings.default_next_step);
        if (defaultNextStep) {
          item.settings.default_next_step = correctNextStep(defaultNextStep);
        }
      break;
      case 'radiobuttons':
      case 'dropdown':
        item.settings.answers.map(
          (answer) => answer.next_step = correctNextStep(parseInt(answer.next_step))
        );
      break;
    }
  });
}
```